# How to disable/reassign F8 key in vncviewer under MacOS?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am connecting to linux machine via [vncviewer for MacOS](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/macos/). Unfortunately, `F8` key is reserved to escape to vncviewer menu, while I need this key to IntelliJ IDEA. Is it possible to reassign this key to another one like `F12`?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution on Windows VNCViewer, probably it would be the same in the macOS.

In the main window of VNCViewer, you should click **File** > **Preferences** > **Expert**, and there is an option **MenuKey**.

After changing this option, you should reconnect.